# Regex for overlapping fixed width matches

Tags: regex

so say I have a string:

'aaggbb'

And I want to find all the groups of type aXXXb where X is any char. 
I thought the regex:

`/(a(?:...)b)/ig`

would do the trick, but it only gets the first one:

'**aaggb**b'

and misses the second one:

'a**aggbb**'

How do I get both?

I searched around for a while trying to figure this out so I hope I didn't miss something very obvious. Thanks!

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: javascript, but I imagined it wouldn't be language specific

Comment: what do you actaully want to catch from 'aaggbb', is it `aggb` or only 3 characters between a and b or what?

Comment: Is it [`(?=(a.{3}b))`](https://regex101.com/r/yB8rW4/1) that you are looking for?

Comment: I'd like to capture the two groups I bolded: **aaggb** and **aggbb**

Comment: Hmm looks like you've got it @stribizhev, is that a positive lookahead you're using that does the trick?

Comment: Yes, the look-ahead makes it possible to get overlapping matches. I posted my answer, please feel free to drop any comments if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for get fixed length substrings, then you need to specifify it with a limiting quantifier `{3}` (match exactly 3 symbols) and use capturing inside a look-ahead to match all substrings:

```
(?=(a.{3}b))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB8rW4/1)

The look-ahead is not consuming characters, and will enable overlapping matches. "Consuming" means that *after the lookahead or lookbehind's closing parenthesis, the regex engine is left standing on the very same spot in the string from which it started looking: it hasn't moved. From that position, then engine can start matching characters again.* (from [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html))

```js
var re = /(?=(a.{3}b))/g; 
var str = 'aaggbb';

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" />
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I wasn't sure of the search terms to use. I bet "overlapping" would have helped me out more. I'll read more about the look-ahead.

Comment: Well, there are tons of similar questions on regex, some differ in just one character to match, and I am not sure if they are all that duplicates :) Your question is actually about overlapping fixed-width matches and after a quick search on SO I could not find a duplicate.

Comment: Lol glad I'm not completely adding cruft :)

Comment: `var str = "aaggbb"; 
    var res = str.match(/(?=(a.{3}b))/g);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res; ` @stribizhev why does this fail is javascript and returns empty array??

Comment: The problem is in the `match` function. [*If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. **Captured groups are not returned.** If there were no matches, the method returns null.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). Since we are interested in the captured texts, we need to rely on `exec` rather than on `match`.

Comment: Ok i think am a bit confused with `consuming characters`, what does it actually mean?? P.S: Am not much into regex..

Comment: "Consuming" means "matching and moving on to the next position in string". You can read more about lookarounds (lookaheads and lookbehinds) at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)